# Postgresql Upsert based on conditition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
   ...
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
    user_id UUID NOT NULL references users (id),
    tag VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
...
}
```

I would like to form a query that inserts a tag based on the following constraints:

1. For a given `user_id` in the `tags` table, all entries must have unique tags
2. Different `user_id`s can have the same tag. For example:

The following should be valid in the `tag` table

| id | user_id | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `some-tag-uuid-1` | `some-user-uuid-1` | foo |
| `some-tag-uuid-2` | `some-user-uuid-1` | bar |
| `some-tag-uuid-3` | `some-user-uuid-2` | foo |

*Note the differences in user_id* .

The following should **NOT** be valid in the `tag` table

| id | user_id | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `some-tag-uuid-1` | `some-user-uuid-1` | foo |
| `some-tag-uuid-2` | `some-user-uuid-1` | foo |

3. If an entry exists, I should return the existing tag id. If not, we insert the new tag
   and return the new tag's id.

#### What I currently have

As of now, the only query I can come up with is split into two parts and the app handles the intermediate logic.

For a given tag to insert e.g.

```json
{id: 'some-tag-uuid-1', user_id: 'some-user-uuid-1', tag: 'busy'};
```

```sql
SELECT id FROM tag WHERE user_id = 'some-user-uuid-1' AND tag = 'busy'
```

From the resulting rows, I then check if it exists, if so, I return the existing `id`, if not I insert the new id in the tag table returning the new `id`.

I'm not sure if this approach is the best approach, and would like a single more performant query (if possible)

Comment: Simply add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `(user_id, tag)` to the `tags` table. Then an duplicate combo will fail and you can do a `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

Comment: For 1. and 2. you need a [UNIQUE constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) covering both columns `user_id` and `tag`. For 3. your keywords are `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` and `RETURNING` of the [INSERT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Thanks @C14L, the `RETURNING` clause provided by @SebDieBln was the extra piece I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @SebDieBln :

1. You add a unique constraint in the `tags` table definition : `CONSTRAINT unique_constraint UNIQUE (user_id, tag)`
2. You add `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` in the `INSERT` statement
3. You add the `RETURNING` clause in the `INSERT` statement in order to get the new tag when inserted
4. But when the `tag` value already exists for the `user_id`, the returned value is `NULL`, so you need to catch the `tag` input value instead.

Finaly you can do everything within a sql function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (IN _user_id UUID , INOUT _tag VARCHAR(200), OUT _rank INTEGER) 
RETURNS record LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
WITH cte AS (INSERT INTO tags (user_id, tag) VALUES (_user_id, _tag) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING tag)
SELECT tag, 1 FROM cte 
UNION
SELECT _tag, 2
ORDER BY 2 
LIMIT 1 ;
$$
```

And you call the sql function to get the expected behavior :

```
SELECT _tag FROM test('some-user-uuid-1', 'busy')
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5948644104ead3da30f95a75a6dcfdb5).